# Adding authentication middleware to redux api

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I created a react-redux webapp, in which the login/signup is done using JWT authentication. This app uses a lot of server api, and due to security reasons each api request needs to accept a valid token, only then it sends back a valid response, else, it simply sends an error object back saying `the token is not valid`.

Now the problem arises when suppose I open my account in one browser, lets say chrome, and then I also open the same account in Firefox, now, obviously the token has expired in chrome, so when I make requests from chrome I simply get the error object returned, what would be good that I have a middleware before each server request which would check the validy of the token and then redirect to login if the token is invalid.

I am quite new to redux and was wondering if something like that is possible, any kind of help is appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: Does not really seem related to Redux at all. How does login happen? How is the token initially signed? JWT auth definitely supports the same user being logged in in multiple browsers. The payload section of the token typically contains information like the username/id and the server-side auth only verifies if the signature matches.

Comment: In my case every time the user logs in a new token is issued for that particular session and that user, if logged in from a different browser, the previous token expires

Comment: So that's a constraint on the server-side auth implementation then. You must have some sort of session management to even know that another user logged in. Usually the point of using JWT in the first place is to not have server-side session management at all. So can you change that implementation or exactly what kind of problem would you like to solve?